# Linear Algebra Eigen Value Question

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I am practicing for my final exam coming up and was having some trouble with this question:

---

$\textbf{Question:}$

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda  = 4$ and corresponding eigenvector $x$. Let $B = 5I - 3A + A^2$. Then

$\textbf{Answer choices:}$

(A) $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $9$.

(B) $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $-3$.

(C) $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $4$.

(D) $x$ is an eigenvector but there is not enough information to determine the corresponding eigenvalue.

(E) $x$ is not necessarily an eigenvector of $B$.

---

What I did to get the answer is state that Ax=λx, so (A+cI)x=(λ+c)x. Using that c is 5 and λ is 4 I got the correct answer of 9, but I am not sure this is the correct way of doing the question. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just calculate $Bx$ using the distributive law. But just to make sure you know the definitions, what does the given information tell you about $Ax$?

Comment: Also, you wrote "A is 4", but you meant $\lambda = 4$, right?

Comment: Is Ax I diagonal matrix then? With the mean diagonal corresponding to the eigenvalue of 4?

Comment: Ax is a not a diagonal matrix. It's an n x 1 column vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at each term individually.

From $Ax = \lambda x$, we have $A^2x = A(Ax) = A(\lambda x) = \lambda (Ax) = \lambda^2 x$.

Similarly, $3Ax = 3(\lambda x) = 3\lambda x$, and $5Ix = 5x$.

Putting these together, we have that $(5I - 3A + A^2) x = 5x - 3\lambda x + \lambda^2 x = (5 - 3\lambda + \lambda^2)x$.  Then $x$ is still an eigenvector of $5I - 3A + A^2$, and its corresponding eigenvalue is $5 - 3\lambda + \lambda^2$.

Plugging in $\lambda = 4$ gives $5 - 3 \cdot 4 + 4^2 = 9$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $P$ is a polynomial and $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $P(A)x = P(\lambda)x$.